# Как заблокировать выделение некоторых checkbox по условию?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как заблокировать выделение некоторых checkbox по условию? К примеру, если выделен `input[value="Animals"]`, чтобы нельзя было выделить `input[value="Insects"]` и наоборот?
Этот пример является минифицированным, чекбоксов и параметров исключения гораздо больше, хотелось бы узнать по какой логике задаются условия.

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Animals">
  Животные
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Insects">
  Насекомые
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Всё просто:

создаёте в *JS* коде мапы с зависимостями и ими потом оперируете. Например

```
let map = {animal: ['insects', 'flies', 'auto'], cars: ['cats', 'burgers', 'phones']}
```

При выборе чекбокса, считываете его данные, и по ключу из объекта вынимаете массив с наименованиями того, что нужно заблочить. В цикле делаете это.

P.S. Кстати, лучше для таких целей оперировать не атрибутом `value`, а `data`- атрибутами.
P.P.S. В качестве мапы можно использовать как обычный объект, так и специальный тип, который так и называется: **[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)**

Comment: Подскажите, Вы не могли бы дать краткий пример с кодом, хотелось бы в новой для меня ситуации зафиксировать правильный способ

Comment: @Alex нет. Считаю что человек должен сам разобраться в предоставленных темах и материалах и попытаться сделать сам, даже если криво косо и с ошибками. Иначе, как раз, будет отточен навык копипаста без включение логических и умоззаключительских способностей..